# Get data from database in form of JSON in PLAY(Scala)

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am new to Play 2.1 and Scala. I am from node.js background & it returns result from database directly in JSON form. What I want is to get the data from database in JSON form in Play(Scala). I have tried Json.toJson but it shows error of deserializer or something. Can anybody find me a solution to this problem with a model & controller description. Thanks in advance.

I am using Mysql database.
Here is model code...

```
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.db.DB

//class definition
case class     Data(Date_Time_id:BigInteger,Details:String,Image:Strig,Status:Boolean,Type:String)

object Model{
    def getDetails(Person_id:Long):Map[BigInteger,Data]={

    DB.withConnection{ implicit c=> 

val result=SQL("""select Date_Time_id,Details,Image,
    ,Status,Type from table1 where  Person_id={perId} 
    """).on("perId"->Person_id)

//mapping result
val detailss=result().map(row=>
        row[BigInteger]("Date_Time_id")->row[BigInteger]("Date_Time_id"),row[String]("Details"),row[String]("Image"),row[Boolean]("Status"),row[String]("Type"))).toMap
    return detailss

}
}
```

I am calling it from controller like:

```
var getResult=Model.getDetails(some Id)
```

Comment: check out http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson

Comment: What kind of database are you using? How are you calling the database? Could you include that code in your question?

Comment: Show us some code... How are you getting data from the database? Some orm or raw sql queries and mapping?

Comment: @EECOLOR i have added the code of model and controller . Can you find me a solution to above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though nobody answered my question, I have found a solution to this problem.Here are few steps for getting data in form of json

```
// Add Dependency in Build.scala file we are using "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.1" for json


val appDependencies = Seq(
// Add your project dependencies here,
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
"com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.1" ,
jdbc,
anorm
)
```

Now you have to code your controller as shown below

```
import com.google.gson.Gson   //import google json library
case class Data(Date_Time_id:BigInteger,Details:String,Image:Strig,Status:Boolean,Type:String)    //create class

var getResult=Model.getDetails(some Id)
val detailsList = postDetails.values.toList  //convert map to list

val myData=new Details(detailsList(0).Date_Time_id,detailsList(0).Details,detailsList(0).Image,detailsList(0).Status,detailsList(0).Type)   //create object and pass data to class
val gson = new Gson                          //create Gson object
val jsonResponse=gson.toJson(myData)        //convert myData to JSON
prinln(jsonResponse)                        //print json to console
```

Output will be like

```
{"Date_Time_id":123,"Details":"blahblah","Image":"abc.jpg","Status":true,"Type":"foo"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to do the following:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Data(...)
object Data {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Data]
}

val x:Data = ???

println(Json.toJson(x))
```